# In memory FAT filesystem

Tags: c++, filesystems

If a have a FAT filesystem implemented in a SDRAM memory block(on a blackfin 537 board) how could I write a file to that memory(file system)?

Comment: If it's in RAM then you can use it as a large `char` array, and use normal C/C++ array syntax.

Comment: Isn't it possible to mount it using /dev/mem?

Comment: If you have it implemented, you'll know how to write. Really, what is your question about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to install a ram disk driver (which makes the RAM look like a block device) and a FAT driver (which will interpret the RAM blocks as a FAT file system). You can now use the regular `std::fstream` functions.